# Move 2 different divs on hover on a third different div

Tags: css, hover

My page has 3 divs that are located horizontally.  I need to make the 2 divs move to the sides of the page (left div move to left, and right div move to right) when the center div is on hover.  I can make the left div move, but the right div isn't moving.  I hope to get this achieved using CSS, if not please advise.  Thanks a lot.

My code is like the below:

```
.container 
   {
    position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
    margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;
    width:50%; height:10%;
   }
.a {position:absolute; bottom:0; left:20px; width:30%;}
.b 
   {
    position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
    margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; width:30%;
   }
.c {position:absolute; bottom:0; right:20px; width:30%;}

.b:hover + .a{
-moz-transform:translatex(-50px);
-ms-transform:translatex(-50px);
-o-transform:translatex(-50px);
-webkit-transform:translatex(-50px);
transform:translatex(-50px);
}

.b:hover + .c{
-moz-transform:translatex(50px);
-ms-transform:translatex(50px);
-o-transform:translatex(50px);
-webkit-transform:translatex(50px);
transform:translatex(50px);
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="b">Div b</div>
    <div class="a">Div a</div>
    <div class="c">Div c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the selectors from + to ~:

.b:hover ~ .a{

.b:hover ~ .c{

http://jsfiddle.net/YYhTS/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [general sibling combinator `~`](http://8.3.2.%20General%20sibling%20combinator) instead of the [adjacent sibling combinator `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)

> **Adjacent sibling combinator**
>   The adjacent sibling combinator is made of the "plus sign" (U+002B, +) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and *the element represented by the first sequence **immediately precedes** the element represented by the second one*.

---

> **General sibling combinator**
>   The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and *the element represented by the first sequence precedes (**not necessarily immediately**) the element represented by the second one*.

So your rules should be

```
.b:hover ~ .a{
 ...
}

.b:hover ~ .c{
 ...
}
```

---

Additionally, for the effect you currently use, you could just change the left/right porperties.. instead of transforming..

Comment: I tried using the left/right properties, it doesn't do a smooth roll out and in. Currently, my code uses the transition property in divs to enable that.  How do I help the divs ease nicely, if I were to use the left/right properties?  Thanks.

Comment: @chris, you can use transitions for left/right changes... check out the http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pNvSv/2/ Although you have to specify in a fixed manner where to move... (*i mean the left/right is absolute positions, and not relative like `translatex` is*)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Learnt something new from you.