# CSS translate button on sibling hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, siblings, translate-animation

I'm trying to create a stack of buttons that will slide out from underneath the top hovered button, but it's not working in [my Codepen](http://codepen.io/dmoz/pen/xIsfL) (http://codepen.io/dmoz/pen/xIsfL).

Here's the code:

### HTML

```
<button class="one"></button>
<button class="two"></button>
<button class="three"></button>
<button class="four"></button>
<button class="five">^</button>
```

### CSS

```
button {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #0078E7;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
}
.one {
  background-color: #3b5997;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 10;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.two {
  background-color: #ba0f16;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 10;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.three {
  background-color: #d64937;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 10;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.four {
  background-color: #0073b2;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 10;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.five {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  color: #888888;
  left: 10;
}
.five:hover ~ .one {
  left: 70px;
}
.five:hover ~ .two {
  left: 130px;
}
.five:hover ~ .three {
  left: 190px;
}
.five:hover ~ .four {
  left: 250px;
}
```

Anyone see why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS3 selector `~` only works for siblings that come AFTER the first element, regardless of how many siblings are between. The CSS2.1 selector `+` works only on the immediate NEXT element. Thus your code won't work since `.five` is the last element. There is no selector for *previous siblings*.

If you move the fifth button before the others and add `z-index` to it, it will work, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kEjwe

UPDATE: As requested, the CodePen example now has a wrapper div rendering the buttons child elements. Thus, the siblings selector is no longer required. This way, the individual buttons can be clicked when the wrapper is hovered.

Comment: Awesome! Worked. I'm still wondering, though, why did `~` work in this case?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924068/move-2-different-divs-on-hover-on-a-third-different-div  and is it the transition easing that causes the boxes underneath to show on the left of the hover-div when they return to the starting position?

Comment: The linked question/answer works because `.b` comes first (then `.a` and `.c`).

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. A semi-related follow-up question: How would I keep the slide-out buttons where they are after the initial hover (so they can be clicked themselves)? This is going to be a social sharing pop-out.

Comment: Sure, but that needs some more alteration of the HTML code because you need at least a wrapper element which is hovered. See updated demo at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kEjwe The wrapper element also allows you to drop the siblings selector since the buttons are now child elements.